# Using Ising model to find the equilbrium situation time dependant

Tags: python, iteration, physics, subplot, matplotlib-animation

I'm very new to python so my code may be messy. I was trying to do this physics homework, using the Ising model, where an array of 16x16 is set with a spin value (-1 or 1) for each cell. Then, using `mcmove(config,iT)`, the equilibrium situation is found for a given temperature, using `calcMag(config)`. The program also computes the total magnetization for each situation.

My problem is that I have achieved the animation of the different arrays (using `matplotlib.animation.ArtistAnimation`), but I would like to animate the magnetization too. My ultimate goal would be to have the six subplots animated and with every frame syncronized: the array for each temperature and its magnetization value at the same frame for the three temperatures.

Here's my code (the previous definitions can be skipped, I think my problem is inside the loop when plotting the magnetization):

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import rand
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

def initialstate(N):
    '''Generates a random spin configuration for initial conditions'''
    state=2*np.random.randint(2,size=(N,N))-1
    return state

def mcmove(config,beta):
    '''Monte Carlo move using Metropolis algorithm'''
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(N):
            #select random spin for NxN system
            a=np.random.randint(0,N)
            b=np.random.randint(0,N)
            s=config[a,b]
            #calculate energy cost of this new configuration (the % is for calculation of periodic boundary conditions)
            nb=config[(a+1)%N,b] + config[a,(b+1)%N]+config[(a-1)%N,b]+config[a,(b-1)%N]
            cost = 2*s*nb
            #flip spin or not, depending on the cost and its Boltzmann factor
            ## (acceptance probability is given by Boltzmann factor with beta=1/kBT)
            if cost<0:
                s*=-1
            elif rand() < np.exp(-cost*beta):
                s*=-1
            config[a,b]=s
    return config

def calcEnergy(config):
    '''Energy of a given configuration'''
    energy = 0
    for i in range(len(config)):
        for j in range(len(config)):
            S = config[i,j]
            nb=config[(i+1)%N,j]+config[i,(j+1)%N] + config[(i-1)%N,j] + config[i,(j-1)%N]
            energy += -nb*S
    return energy/4.

def calcMag(config):
    '''Magnetization of a given configuration'''
    mag = np.sum(config)
    return mag

nt = 64         # number of temperature points
N = 16           # size of the lattice, NxX
eqSteps = 10    # number of MC sweeps for equilibration

n1= 1.0/(eqSteps*N*N)
Magnetization = np.zeros(eqSteps)

n=0

tem='Temperature = '

c=0
f=0
id=1


images1 = []
images2 = []
images3 = []
#images4 = []
#images5 = []
#images6 = []

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2,3,1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2,3,2)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(2,3,3)
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(2,3,4)
ax5 = fig.add_subplot(2,3,5)
ax6 = fig.add_subplot(2,3,6)

list=[[0.5, ax1, images1, ax4],
      [1.5, ax2, images2, ax5],
      [3.0, ax3, images3, ax6]] 

for T, c, p, g in list:    
    
    E1 = M1 = E2 = M2 = 0

    config = initialstate(N)
    iT = 1.0/T
    iT2 = iT*iT
    
    print ("Simulation at temperature T=",T)
    titles = tem + str(T)
    
    for i in range(eqSteps):   # equilibrate
        mcmove(config,iT)      # Monte Carlo moves
            
        im = c.imshow(config, animated=True)
        c.set_title(titles)
        p.append([im])
    
        Mag = calcMag(config)
        M1 = M1 + Mag
        Magnetization[i]  = n1*M1
        
        g.plot(i, abs(Magnetization[i]),'.',color="#348ABD")
        g.set_title('Magnetization')

        
ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, images1, interval=50, blit=True, repeat_delay=0)
ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, images2, interval=50, blit=True, repeat_delay=0)
ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, images3, interval=50, blit=True, repeat_delay=0)
```

**THANK YOU SO MUCH** in advance.

About more trivial things I would also like some help in:

- Can I remove the axis from the arrays?
- Can I have the same axis for the magnetization plots for every frame?
- How do I put xlabels and ylabels on the magnetization plots?
- Can I put a label in the figure that updates with every frame? I want this for enumarating them